# Replace Telerik filter TextBox with DropDownList issue

Tags: jquery, telerik

I'm overriding the basis Telerik filter which looks like :

[image]

and I change it to be like this :

[image]

and I handle that in Telerik GRID  while loading the the grid .OnLoad("onListingLoad") as following :

```
        $(this).find("a.t-link:contains('State')").nextUntil().children(".t-filter").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {

            $(".t-filter-help-text:contains('And')").nextUntil(".t-button").andSelf().remove();

            $(".t-filter-operator").each(function () {
                $(this).val("substringof");
            });

            var select = "<select id='customFilter' data-val='false'> \
                            <option value=''>[Select State]</option> \
                            <option value='Approved'>Approved</option> \
                            <option value='Assigned'>Assigned</option> \
                            <option value='End State'>End State</option> \
                        </select>";
            $("#documentListing").find(":text").replaceWith(select);

        });
    });
```

When I select item in the dropdownlist then press filter an error occurred in the last line at this JQUERY code in jquery.validate.js :

```
normalizeRules: function(rules, element) {
                            // handle dependency check
                            $.each(rules, function(prop, val) {
                                            // ignore rule when param is explicitly false, eg. required:false
                                            if (val === false) {
                                                            delete rules[prop];
                                                            return;
                                            }
                                            if (val.param || val.depends) {
```

and the error is :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of undefined "

I tried hard to remove the rules form the new DropDownList or copy it form the TextBox before removing it but with no success.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that `rules` still contains references to the elements you are removing to change the look of your filter. When you `.remove()` for the filter, remove that element from `rules` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I tried to remove rules as webnoob suggested but it didn't work, the problem seems to be in the new "select" element, i wonder if there is a way to stop firing the rules for this new element.